# service to clear clipboard in android to prevent copy paste

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to prevent copy pasting of my `mp4` and `pdf` files. So I want to clear clipboard containing my video to paste before it's pasted somewhere. When clipboard takes my file address for pasting then I'd like to clear clipboard to prevent copy-pasting. Alternatively I'd like to force close the app that's copying my file...
Is it possible? If yes then how?
I'm new to android please provide a detailed and comprehensible solution........

I've seen some site where this was suggested:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Is it not possible to change permissions to your files instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clipboard can only copy a file URI, not the file itself, and that too only if your application implements a [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) and encodes an identifier on the URI.

Users cannot simply copy your file paths by default. You have to code this behaviour explicitly.

So, you don't need to clear the clipboard since file paths won't be copied to the clipboard in the first place.

Your files are safe.

Also see the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html).

Comment: I know clipboard only copy file's url not file. But i m new to it. I can't understand what you have commented. means implements a contentprovider and encodes an identifier on the url? I don't understand this. can you explain it in details?????? Thank you for your answer

Comment: You have to implement a ContentProvider if you want your files to be shared. Since you don't want your files to be shared, you don't have to do anything. By default, your files are private to you only.